# How would I create global scripts within HTML Pages so I don't need to constantly change the location?

Tags: css, html, variables, global

I recently took a beginners HTML and CSS class, and I absolutely loved it. CSS is such a powerful language, and HTML is great too.

However, one thing I noticed my teacher of this class told me, is how do I create global scripts to work with each individual page? This way im constantly not changing the file path of my CSS stylesheet, and other similar stuff. For example, when I went ahead and created a new folder for a new location, my CSS stylesheet was not found, thus making the page look like good ol' HTML.

The main ones I want to keep in mind is the navigation bar on the top, Footer on the bottom, and the CSS StyleSheet.

If anyone can help me out, it would be appreciated. Remember I am a minor at this. I do know a lot of CSS and HTML, and minor javascript (And python if that helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Global Scripts' your teacher is referring to are individual, external files. This is good practice as inline code can bloat a page's size, whereas an external file can be cached for later use and not have to be re-downloaded again. From a maintainability standpoint it is also good practice as you will only have to edit the external CSS file to change the look and feel of your website.

The easiest way to create an external CSS file is to:

1. Create a folder named CSS
2. Within that folder create a file called style.css
3. On your html pages link to that style.css file using the following code: <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

So as an example, your HTML page should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Put all your CSS code within that style.css file and all HTML pages will have the CSS properties applied to it. Make sure you provide the correct path to the CSS file (style.css) wherever it may be located on your setup. You made a great life choice dwelling into programming. Best of luck, you are the future!

Comment: Giancarlo, Thank you so much, I do agree, I am the future if I put my mind towards it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to stick with absolute paths when linking your CSS and javascript. It is quite likely that you are using relative paths when linking your other scripts.

**Absolute path**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/main.css">
                                             ^
```

Notice the slash at the beggining of the path. An absolute path will look for the file from the root of your web directory.

**Relative path**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
                                            ^
```

Notice the slash is absent in the relative path. This means that it will look for a folder called CSS that contains the main.css in the same directory as the currently loaded web page.

If you are looking for a more portable solution I would recommend looking at PHP. A basic starting point for relative paths using PHP is shown below.

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the feedback!